# findbyidandupdate not updating user when ive $set, what's wrong with my function, req.body returning nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I get the 200 response but it doesn't seem to update the user, im also using the token to match it with the user id and then checking if they're updating the password in which case I will hash it with bcrypt.

I have console logged the req.body and its returning an empty object and thus i think this is why its not updating, I'm wondering why this is the case?

```
router.put('/:id', verify, async(req, res) => {
    if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {
        if (req.body.password){
            req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 5)
        }
        try {
            const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: req.body},{new: true})
            res.status(200).send(updatedUser)
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).send(error)
            }
    } else {
        res.status(403).send("You are not allowed to update this user")
    }
})
```

Here is the schema for the user:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    profilePic: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    isAdmin: {
     type: Boolean,
     default: false
    } 
}, {timestamp: true}
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

Comment: What does updatedUser look like?

Comment: just returns the old user information

Comment: Please show us the document on the db, and the query with all the parameters

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an express backend, right?

If your req.body is empty, obviously nothing will be updated.
Be sure to send request formatted as JSON (like {isAdmin: true}) and to use something to parse body request, like bodyParser (https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)

If you need more help, please post your full api request, a console.log of your req.body and a full .explain() (https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/explain)